# Format a duration for soccer (football)

Tags: java, android, datetime, formatting

In soccer (most places, they call it football), the game time is shown as `mm:ss`, even if there are more than 59 minutes, so if at one hour 22 minutes, 32 seconds into the game, it would be displayed as `82:32`.

I have the time as an `android.text.format.Time`, with hours, minutes and seconds set, which means that I can easily have it as a number of milliseconds since the epoch. Looking through the formatting options (like `Time.format(String)`), the format specifiers for minutes seems to always have the range `[0, 59)`. Short of writing my own formatter (not hard, but I'm worried about localization), is there a format call that will do what I want here? Thanks.

My specific fears about localization are as follows:

1. Time separator (':' vs. '.' or some other thing--I don't know the separators that various locales use).
2. Order. I could imagine some cultures displaying `32:82` in the example from above.
3. Something even more horrible that I haven't thought of yet.

Obviously, 1 and 2 are solvable with a smart, localized format string with good comments. 3 scares me, but I may just be being paranoid.

Comment: Why are you worried about localization if those are just numbers?

Comment: Just keep the hour and minute as a number that you can manipulate yourself

Comment: @gian1200--edited to add an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I really think you'll be best either
a) not using any Time.format at all - just doing simple math to figure figure out the minutes and seconds and then displaying mm:ss, or
b) using localized format strings if you absolutely need them.

Your first two worries will not be a problem in almost all cases: using a colon to separate minutes and seconds is common across many cultures, as is displaying the minutes before the seconds. In fact, it's the ISO standard: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

If you're really worried about it and want to do a little investigating, I would find videos of soccer matches being broadcast in different languages / locations. I just found one on YouTube in Chinese, and it's using mm:ss to display the time.